# how do I enable firewall zones for NetworkManager

Tags: network-manager, firewall

[image: It is always disabled]

I am trying to use the default network manager for ubuntu 13.10 to connect to networks. Despite any config changes for example, enabling UFW, does not allow for the changing of this profile scheme. It is remains always faded as shown in the picture.
In my experience with Fedora, this similar network management style works right out of the box. Is this firewall zone config meant for a different firewall and if so, which? I've tried googling for 'ubuntu networkmanager firewall zone' but haven't gotten any relevant results.
Please advise, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because there is no integration with ufw.

Just install firewalld.

Comment: ahhh thank you. that's what i wasn't sure about, thank you!

Comment: You could include a link in your answer to this handy front-end for firewalld - https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/saucy/firewall-applet/ which makes it a lot more approachable.

Comment: @TimAbell The link just goes to the root of the ubuntu site.

Comment: @sergio there is no explanation in the answer. So is of little value.

Comment: here's the main page for firewall applet for firewalld: https://firewalld.org/documentation/utilities/firewall-applet.html

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor I added another answer with a bit more info

Answer (score 0):

To get automatic switching of zones I used `firewalld` with the GUI [`firewall-applet`](https://firewalld.org/documentation/utilities/firewall-applet.html), installed as follows:

```
sudo apt install firewall-applet
```

You can then use the user interfaces to configure allowed services/ports on different zones, and to configure which connections belong to which zones:

[image]