# Limit bandwidth for background applications on slow network

Tags: networking, wireless

When I am at slow and/or paid networks (i.e. in public transport wifi of while tethering) I want to browse as fast as possible, so I don't want Ubuntu to download software updates, torrents, etc.

There are many apps that monitor or limit applications, but I can't find an app that works like the 'disable background usage' or 'disable while not on wifi or while roaming' like Android has. I would be great to have an app that disables/limit certain applications when the wifi network is considered as a slow/expensive network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create a firewall profile that blocks everything except `http` and `dns` and set your update mirror to one that only accepts the `ftp` protocol:

1. Firewall configuration:

   ```
   apt-get install gufw
   ```

Now go to the dash, and type `firewall` and click the sole icon remaining and you'll see:

[image: Firewall public]

**Begin warning:** *From now on, until you see **End warning**, you will not have access to the Internet!*

- Take the "public" profile (or another one you're currently now using) and set everything to "reject" (as in the picture above)
- Click the <kbd>+</kbd> below "rules" and click on the "Simple" tab and fill out the screen as follows:

[image: DNS traffic]

and press <kbd>Add</kbd>

Then fill out the screen as follows:

[image: HTTP traffic]

and press <kbd>Add</kbd>, then <kbd>Close</kbd>

**End Warning**

Your rules section should now look like this:

[image: Minimal rules]

2. Mirror config

In the Netherlands, there is only one mirror that supports ftp only: `Ftpserv-tudelft-nl`, for all other countries, look [here for the full list](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archivemirrors) and choose your own.

Now go to the dash again and type `Software Updater` and again, click the sole icon available, click <kbd>Settings</kbd>, the "Ubuntu Software" tab, "Download from:" and choose <kbd>Other</kbd>, take the country of your choice and the server of your choice:

[image: NL,TuDelft]

### And voilà: you can only surf the Internet and nothing else can happen any more!

**No updates, no email, no Skype, no FTP, no HTTPS, no nothing! Only DNS look-ups and web surfing**  If you would like to have more then the absolute minimal available, have a look at [IANA assigned port numbers](http://www.iana.org/assignments/service-names-port-numbers/service-names-port-numbers.xhtml) and add any other protocol numbers you would need.

***To revert back to normal use:***  just open the `firewall` in the dash again, Click on <kbd>Public</kbd> and then click on <kbd>Home</kbd> and you're back to where you were!

Comment: Don't thank me!  ;-) If you like my answer, just click the little grey **☑** under the "0" now turning it into beautiful green.  If you do not like my answer, click on the little grey down-arrow below the 0, and if you *really* like my answer, click on the little grey checkmark *and* the little up-arrow...  If you have any further questions, go to http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask

Comment: Graag gedaan!  ;-)

Comment: Dankjewel! ;-). The only thing I'm missing is the ability to select a default firewall zone for each network. I'm using KDE and I just saw a 'Firewall-zone' select box in my network manager, but I can't select anything. I'll look for more information and keep you posted.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no integration: http://askubuntu.com/questions/406073/how-do-i-enable-firewall-zones-for-networkmanager

Comment: AskUbuntu General room?  Chat???